# SQL Update With Inner join and SUM

Tags: sql, sql-update, inner-join

I have 2 tables(say T1 and T2). as follows
T1  =>
-*-------------------

C1 | C2| C3|

-*-------------------
  R1    |    W1      |    0        |
  R2    |    W1      |    0        |
  R3    |    W2      |    0        |

T2 =>
-*-------------

C1| C2|

-*-------------
 R1  |  5       |
 R1  |  7       |
 R2  |  4       |

What I have is T1C2. From that I want to update T1C3 with Sum of T2C2 using C1 as joining key i.e. in this case for T1C2 = W1, I want T1C3 to be updated as 12 , 4 for R1 and R2 values respectively
Query That I tried is

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1C3 = SUM(T2C2)
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1C1 = T2C1
WHERE T1C2 = W1
```

This gives error 
"An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement." 
Why this error ? and any idea on how to achieve this please.

Answer (score 0):

you can use aggregate functions only in select-statements. try:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1C3 = (select SUM(T2C2)
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1C1 = T2C1
WHERE T1C2 = W1)
```